# React - Setting state inside use Effect problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i ve got simple problem, just solving for 2 hours and cannot find solution(i am new to React)

I want to set State to true when all conditions inside use Effect are true. Use effect runs every time i click on button

```
const [allBtnOff, setAllBtnOff] = React.useState(false)

React.useEffect(() => {
        
        
        if (btnOff.ER1 === true && 
            btnOff.ER2 === true &&
            btnOff.ER3 === true &&
            btnOff.ER4 === true &&
            btnOff.ER5 === true &&
            btnOff.ER6 === true &&
            btnOff.Dreier === true &&
            btnOff.Vierer === true &&
            btnOff.Full === true &&
            btnOff.Kleine === true &&
            btnOff.Grobe === true &&
            btnOff.Kniffel === true &&
            btnOff.Chance === true  
            ) 
            {
                setAllBtnOff(prevState => !prevState)
                console.log(allBtnOff)

            }
    },[btnOff])
```

Problem is, that its always one step back so i have to click two times on button to set it true.

**For more details:**

I click a button and then it will set it true and will disable button. Same time use effect will run, so i need extra click button to check if conditions are true. Any solutions?

EDIT: (maybe understanding code more will help)

```
// BTN OFF/ON after passing score
    const [btnOff, setBtnOff] = React.useState({
        ER1: false,
        ER2: false,
        ER3: false,
        ER4: false,
        ER5: false,
        ER6: false,
        Dreier: false,
        Vierer: false,
        Full: false,
        Kleine: false,
        Grobe: false,
        Kniffel: false,
        Chance: false
      })

// Passing score and disabling button 
      function handleClick(event) {

        setTotalValues(prevState => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                [event.target.name]: Score
            }     
        })

        setBtnOff(prevState => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                [event.target.name]: true
            }
        })
}

return (
 <div className="score--inside">
                <h3>1ER:</h3>
                <p>{totalValues.ER1}</p>
                <button disabled={btnOff.ER1 && true} name="ER1" onClick={handleClick}>Add score</button>
            </div>

// ...MULTIPLE SCORE--INSIDE BOXES 

)
```

Comment: Consider having a look at `useReducer`. Also have a look at `Object.values` and `Array.prototype.every`

Comment: Yea i will definitely make objects more efficient. Thanks for tip

Answer (score 0):

Create another useEffect and follow this:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
        
        
        if (allBtnOff) console.log(allBtnOff)

            
    },[allBtnOff])
```

Comment: I dont understand, this doesnt solve the problem.